# Inspector seems to prevent user-defined classes from being cleared when connected to a figure

Tags: class, matlab, inspector, figures

I am writing a basic GUI using classes in MATLAB. It involves basic uicontrols() and [GridLayout](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29472-gridlayout) components. Normally, if I close the figure and issue a 'clear classes' everything is fine. However, if I inspect the figure created by the class, it seems to keep the objects around to where I cannot clear them.
So far, the only solution I have found is to restart MATLAB.

Concerning my code, I do not store references to my class in any controls via 'UserData'.

Has anyone else ran into this sort of problem? Is there another solution to this?

Comment: what do you mean by "inspect the figure"?

Comment: @amro - I assume he means that [`inspect`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/inspect.html) command.

Comment: I see.. As last resort, you could always use `get`/`set` to manipulate the properties on the command line

Answer (score 0):

That sounds very odd, and I cannot reproduce this. Using the following code,

```
h = figure();
o1 = uicontrol('Style','text','String','hello','position',[ 10 20 80 20]); 
o2 = uicontrol('Style','edit','String','hello','position',[110 20 80 20]); 

inspect(h);
```

if I close the window, the inspect window goes completely blank. Try this out.